# How could I open parentheses which have an addition inside and a bitwise xor outside?

Tags: systems-of-equations

How could I open parentheses which have an addition inside and a bitwise xor outside?

I have a system of equations:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
y - x = c \\
y \oplus x = d
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

$x, y$ - positive (32bit) integer variables, which I want to find.

$c, d$ - integer constants.

$\oplus$ - bitwise xor.

I can make a first step by showing that $y = c + x$ and so $(c+x) \oplus x = d$. How could I find the $x$ from the last equation?

I was able to come up with one more step. By applying the xor $x$ to both sides we get $c+x = d \oplus x$.

If there are any $c$ and $d$ for which it is impossible to solve the system, then you may just not consider such $c$ and $d$.

Comment: What domain are you working with?

Comment: @copper.hat, just playing around with leetcode. If you are interested in details [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/set-mismatch/) is the [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/set-mismatch/). In the referenced problem I am able to find the $c$ and $d$ in linear time and constant space. So, I am left with tackling the $x$ and $y$. :)

Comment: I don't understand what space you are in. Presumably something like $\mathbb{B}^n$ in which case is subtraction twos complement?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are just usual variables of $int$ type.

Comment: Your system will not (necessarily) have unique solutions.

Comment: You have $x=y \oplus d$.

Comment: @paw88789, I updated my question a bit.

Comment: You might want to elaborate that you are working with finite bit size.

Comment: @copper.hat, done.

Comment: There may not be a solution, for example if $c=1 1 \cdots 1, d = 0$ then there are no $x,y$ satisfying the equation.

Comment: @copper.hat, let me update my question. :)